# ValidateAntiForgeryToken filter fails on requests sent by Kendo UI Grid.Read() method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've configured my ASP.NET Core application to globally enforce a token validation filter:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(ConfigureMvcOptions =>
{
    ConfigureMvcOptions.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

I have also globally configured all request methods to contain the necessary cookie:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("RequestVerificationToken", tokenSet.RequestToken!,
        new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
    return next(context);
});
```

This works as expected for all Ajax requests and ASP.NET requests involving a native form field. Where this breaks down is in some requests sent by a Kendo UI `Grid.Read()` method, similar to the one below:

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(x => x.Action("ReadWarningMessages", "UserWarningMessages", new { providerID = Model.ProviderHeaderData.ProviderId })
            .Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
```

What is curious is that not all `Grid.Read()` methods return the `400 Bad Request` message when token validation is enforced, some work fine. What is more curious is that when inspecting the request headers once a `400 Bad Request` response message is received, I see that they contain identical values for `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery` and the `RequestVerificationToken` cookie to the values present in successful request headers.

To clarify, both requests that are successful and those that receive a 400 error code response (Kendo Grid.Read() requests) have identical headers. These consist of a 190 character `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.b2cK7oVvzPo` cookie and a 222 character `RequestVerificationToken` cookie, in addition to two session cookies.

The values of these cookies are identical for successful and  failed requests.

Comment: maybe a red herring.  I would look into the size of the returned data.  (400 bad request can be caused by running over the limit... which you can increase if needed... can you include full exception details?)  (Not familiar with Kendo UI, but it looks like that's a GET so I don't think any antiforgery check is made at that point...?)

Comment: @browsermator One thing I've noticed is that decorating any problematic controller method with `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` immediately resolves the 400 error.... no exception is actually thrown, even with Common Runtime Exceptions set to trigger a break.  The response header and response do not contain any information relevant to the 400 error.

Comment: might need app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); to see full exception?    Now that I look at the question again, though, not sure you are doing this correctly.  The idea of that non-http-only cookie is for the front-end to read that value and then include it as a custom header on next state-changing request.  You'd set the backend to read that via antiforgery options... i.e.:  builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "Xsrf-Token"; 

});  Your front-end would send the value of that RequestVerificationToken cookie as "Xsrf-Token" header.

Comment: Otherwise, you'd add the AntiForgeryToken as a hidden field in a form sent as a standard POST.  (You wouldn't need to add that non-http-only cookie to all your requests in this case... by default ASP.NET will read the hidden form field.)

Comment: though adding the non-http-only cookie as you are doing now does help prevent CRIME/BREACH attacks.  They're useful even if you don't use them.  You may also be able to add that value as a JSON property.  Just use the same name as the normal hidden field uses... (seems like ASP.NET should read that?...)

Comment: @browsermator adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` unfortunately still doesn't show any detailed information, but I can toggle using the decorator `IgnoreAntiForgeryToken] and surmise that this filter is the cause of the problem. Additionally, it is notable that Ajax calls and ASP.NET form fields are working as expected, the problem is specific to the Kendo Grid.Read() method which is really just an abstraction for an Ajax call. Examining the request headers I see they are identical to successful request headers... this is the biggest mystery for me.

Comment: what controller is hit and what verb is used?  Don't think a GET should trigger any antiforgery validation.  Does the non-http-only cookie get updated after the read?

Comment: I have a feeling that what is happening here is about async requests, and one of them is using an old anti-forgery token.  I believe each time antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens() is called you're going to be updating that value (or rotating the key used to encrypt/decrypt the antiforgery token)  Since that key has been updated, the decrypted value won't match the http-only cookie.

Comment: To avoid that you might not set a cookie when this particular endpoint is hit (whatever the kendo bit is calling).  ex: app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;  if (requestPath!="kendos/endpoint") { ... add non-http-only cookie... }

Comment: @browsermator I am working on updating a legacy application that contains dozens of controllers with hundreds of methods in total... a variety of controllers are hit and while most are GET requests there are a few POST requests that likewise fail validation. The cookie being updated after the read (likely by some other middleware or methods internal to Kendo) is possible but the end result is that these failed requests have cookie values identical to successful requests.

Comment: each time you use the standard token in a form, I believe that GetAndStoreTokens() method is called by the middleware. (i.e. "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" ) The next POST is expected to have that token.  But if GetAndStoreTokens gets called again before that POST happens I think you'll fail validation.  (Same would happen when opening the form in a separate tab and then trying to submit the first tab, methinks...)

Comment: When the application loads dozens of async GET / POST requests are fired... I think you are correct in that this is an async request mismatch issue with respect to the token values